# Pandas dataframe transform columns to json columns using apply or vectorization

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

Below  is the given dataframe coming from sql for eg:

| id | days | type | delta | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | X | 1 | 0.1 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 30 | Y | 2 | 0.2 | 0.6 |
| 1 | 60 | X | 1 | 0.3 | 0.7 |
| 1 | 60 | Y | 2 | 0.4 | 0.8 |

Transforming data frame, I want to achieve something like this:

| id | day_30 | day_60 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {A: {X1: 01, Y2: 0.2}, B: {X1: 0.5, Y2: 0.6} | {A: {X1: 0.3, Y2: 0.4}, B: {X1: 0.7, Y2: 0.8} |

Currently I am able to achieve this by group by Id, then group by Days and do iterrows. But it's very slow for millions of rows. How can I make it faster any apply or vectorization example to do the same would be very helpfull.

current code:

```
grp = df.groupby('id')
row_list = []
for name, df_grp in grp:
  o_row = [id]
  day_grp = df_grp.groupby('days')
    for d_name, df_day_grp:
      a_dict = {}
      b_dict = {}
      for idx, row in df_day_grp.iterrows():
        a_dict[f'{row['type']}{row['delta']}] = row['A']
        b_dict[f'{row['type']}{row['delta']}] = row['B']
      row_dict = { 'A': a_dict, 'B': b_dict }
      o_row.append(json_dumps(row_dict))
 row_list.append(o_row)

df = pd.DataFrame(row_list, columns=cols)
```

I am guessing creating the new dataframe and using the iterrows could be the reason for slowness.
Any ideas? How I can achieve similar by using apply or assign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First join `type` with `delta` with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for use and remove column `delta`, then use custom lambda function per groups in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) for create nested dictionaries and last reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
c = ['A','B']
df['type'] = df['type'] + df.pop('delta').astype(str)

f = lambda x:  x.set_index('type')[c].to_dict()
df = df.groupby(['id','days']).apply(f).unstack().add_prefix('day_').reset_index()
print (df)
days  id                                             day_30  \
0      1  {'A': {'X1': 0.1, 'Y2': 0.2}, 'B': {'X1': 0.5,...   

days                                             day_60  
0     {'A': {'X1': 0.3, 'Y2': 0.4}, 'B': {'X1': 0.7,...
```

Comment: Thanks, this code is definitely faster than iterrows, i can see around 6X improvement in processing. will go through the documentation of unstack and apply to find out more details.